# What are the parameters passed to Vue constructor?/

Tags: vue.js, frontend

I'm totally a newbie in front end struggeling to wrap my head around it.

I have a question in Vue, for which I could't find answer anywhere: What does the 'vuetify' object here mean in the Vue constructor? I do know what veutify is, but why is it passed to the Vue constructor?

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

I have checked the Vue document https://012.vuejs.org/api/options.html
Every option has it's reserved name, like **data**, **methods** etc. But there are no definition of passing a 3rd party library or object to it.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: You can pass plugins to vue, a plugin is just a simple object with an install method, so you could pass router, i18n and so on to vue

Answer (score 0):

You can pass custom or 3rd-party options/libraries so you can use them in your Vue Application. Those options are available in `vm.$options`.

```js
new Vue({
  customOption: 'foo',
  created: function () {
    console.log(this.$options.customOption) // -> 'foo'
  }
})
```

[https://012.vuejs.org/api/instance-properties.html#vm-\$options](https://012.vuejs.org/api/instance-properties.html#vm-%5C$options)